# White space between tags is breaking my layout

Tags: css, layout, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I know i could "remove the white space" but that is so inconvenient. There are so many places in the html where i have some inline-block element and it would be hell to go and look for every one of them.

Is there a way to make this white space not appear?

This is my site, as you can see the spaces are breaking my layout: http://www.fashionstore.al/

Comment: What are we looking at? Is this spam? What whitespace? Where? Provide the relevant code here. Questions questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of "cheating". The way I used to do it before I learned any server-side code was this:

```
<div id="container"><!--
   --><div class="block">Text</div><!--
   --><div class="block">More text</div><!--
--></div>
```

By commenting out the whitespace, it no longer causes problems for layout but still lets you separate the lines.

With server-side code, it's easier:

```
<?php
    echo '<div id="container">'
            .'<div class="block">Text</div>'
            .'<div class="block">More text</div>'
        .'</div>';
?>
```

Or, another method:

```
<?php ob_start(function($c) {return preg_replace("/>\s+</","><",$c);}); ?>
<div id="container">
    <div class="block">Text</div>
    <div class="block">More text</div>
</div>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i ended up writing a function in php that stripped the white space off before output and it fixed the problem